# Adding a calendar with ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL to Android 4 makes its calendar crash

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-calendar

I want to add a new calendar to Android that does not get synchronized. I have written an App that does this using the new CalendarContract API from API level 14. The following code works fine. I can see the new calendar in Android's calendar app and add events to it.

The problem is that the Android calendar app crashes when I select: Menu -> Calendars to display -> Calendars to sync

Is there something wrong in my code or is it a bug in Android calendar?

Mind that I do not want to actually use a sync adapter. The documentation of CalendarContract.Calendars says that this is not needed: "If a local calendar is required an app can do so by inserting as a sync adapter and using an ACCOUNT_TYPE of ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL." I understand that "inserting as a sync adapter" means to append (CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true") to the URI.

```
public class CalendarMapper {

private static final String ACCOUNT_NAME = "private";
private static final String INT_NAME_PREFIX = "priv";

private static Uri buildCalUri() {
    return CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI
            .buildUpon()
            .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true")
            .appendQueryParameter(Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, ACCOUNT_NAME)
            .appendQueryParameter(Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, CalendarContract.ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL)
            .build();
}

private static ContentValues buildContentValues(Calendar calendar) {
    String dispName = calendar.getName();  //Calendar.getName() returns a String
    String intName = INT_NAME_PREFIX + dispName;
    final ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, ACCOUNT_NAME);
    cv.put(Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, CalendarContract.ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL);
    cv.put(Calendars.NAME, intName);
    cv.put(Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME, dispName);
    cv.put(Calendars.CALENDAR_COLOR, calendar.getColor());  //Calendar.getColor() returns int
    cv.put(Calendars.CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL, Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_OWNER);
    cv.put(Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT, ACCOUNT_NAME);
    cv.put(Calendars.VISIBLE, 1);
    cv.put(Calendars.SYNC_EVENTS, 1);
    return cv;
}

public static void addCalendar(Calendar calendar, ContentResolver cr) {
    if (calendar == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    final ContentValues cv = buildContentValues(calendar);

    Uri calUri = buildCalUri();
    cr.insert(calUri, cv);
}

}
```

Here is the Stack Trace of the Exception that causes the calendar app to crash:

```
  03-22 07:12:39.437: E/AndroidRuntime(9730): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  03-22 07:12:39.437: E/AndroidRuntime(9730): java.lang.NullPointerException
  03-22 07:12:39.437: E/AndroidRuntime(9730):   at com.android.calendar.selectcalendars.SelectSyncedCalendarsMultiAccountAdapter.bindGroupView(SelectSyncedCalendarsMultiAccountAdapter.java:324)
  03-22 07:12:39.437: E/AndroidRuntime(9730):   at android.widget.CursorTreeAdapter.getGroupView(CursorTreeAdapter.java:207)
  03-22 07:12:39.437: E/AndroidRuntime(9730):   at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getView(ExpandableListConnector.java:445)
  03-22 07:12:39.437: E/AndroidRuntime(9730):   at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2033)
  03-22 07:12:39.437: E/AndroidRuntime(9730):   at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1772)
  03-22 07:12:39.437: E/AndroidRuntime(9730):   at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
  03-22 07:12:39.437: E/AndroidRuntime(9730):   at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:732)
  03-22 07:12:39.437: E/AndroidRuntime(9730):   at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1611)
  03-22 07:12:39.437: E/AndroidRuntime(9730):   at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1863)
  03-22 07:12:39.437: E/AndroidRuntime(9730):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
  03-22 07:12:39.437: E/AndroidRuntime(9730):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
  03-22 07:12:39.437: E/AndroidRuntime(9730):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
  03-22 07:12:39.437: E/AndroidRuntime(9730):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1486)
  03-22 07:12:39.437: E/AndroidRuntime(9730):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
  03-22 07:12:39.437: E/AndroidRuntime(9730):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
  03-22 07:12:39.437: E/AndroidRuntime(9730):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
  03-22 07:12:39.437: E/AndroidRuntime(9730):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
  03-22 07:12:39.437: E/AndroidRuntime(9730):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
  03-22 07:12:39.437: E/AndroidRuntime(9730):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
  03-22 07:12:39.437: E/AndroidRuntime(9730):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
  03-22 07:12:39.437: E/AndroidRuntime(9730):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1486)
  03-22 07:12:39.437: E/AndroidRuntime(9730):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
  03-22 07:12:39.437: E/AndroidRuntime(9730):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
  03-22 07:12:39.437: E/AndroidRuntime(9730):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
  03-22 07:12:39.437: E/AndroidRuntime(9730):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
  03-22 07:12:39.437: E/AndroidRuntime(9730):   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
  03-22 07:12:39.437: E/AndroidRuntime(9730):   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
  03-22 07:12:39.437: E/AndroidRuntime(9730):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1489)
  03-22 07:12:39.437: E/AndroidRuntime(9730):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
  03-22 07:12:39.437: E/AndroidRuntime(9730):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  03-22 07:12:39.437: E/AndroidRuntime(9730):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  03-22 07:12:39.437: E/AndroidRuntime(9730):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
  03-22 07:12:39.437: E/AndroidRuntime(9730):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  03-22 07:12:39.437: E/AndroidRuntime(9730):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
  03-22 07:12:39.437: E/AndroidRuntime(9730):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
  03-22 07:12:39.437: E/AndroidRuntime(9730):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
  03-22 07:12:39.437: E/AndroidRuntime(9730):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an Android bug and apparently will be fixed: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27474